# Mean of matrix multiplied by a scalar vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```py
>>> a = np.arange(9)
>>> a.shape = (3,3)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> c = np.empty((4,3,3))
>>> for i in range(len(c)):
...     c[i] = a*b[i]
... 
>>> c
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

       [[ 0.,  2.,  4.],
        [ 6.,  8., 10.],
        [12., 14., 16.]],

       [[ 0.,  3.,  6.],
        [ 9., 12., 15.],
        [18., 21., 24.]],

       [[ 0.,  4.,  8.],
        [12., 16., 20.],
        [24., 28., 32.]]])
>>> np.mean(c,axis=0)
array([[ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ],
       [ 7.5, 10. , 12.5],
       [15. , 17.5, 20. ]])
```

I have a matrix a and a scalar vector b. I want to get the mean of the matrix multiplied by the scalar vector. Now I have to construct a c as the intermediate variable. Any better way to do this?

Comment: Just use `a * b.mean()`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "better", in objective terms.

Answer (score 1):

The above is equivalent to multiplying `a` with the *mean* of `b`. Indeed, we can simply define this as:

```
>>> a * np.mean(b)
array([[ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ],
       [ 7.5, 10. , 12.5],
       [15. , 17.5, 20. ]])
```

This works since you here each time defining a submatrix `ck` as `ck=a×bk`. If you later calculate the mean `d` of `c`, then we know that `dij=∑k aij×bk/n`. But since `aij` does not depend on `k`, we can thus rewrite this to `dij=aij×∑k bk/n` and thus we obtain the mean of the `b`.

Comment: Thanks. What if I do want to get c, meaning matrix * a scalar vector, take the matrix as one element?

Comment: @QiangHuang: I am a bit confused what result you aim to achieve. The question here seems to suggest that you want the `np.mean(c, axis=0)`, but without constructing such matrix in the first place. You can do that with `a * np.mean(b)`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm asking a separate question. Meaning that how can I get c directly from a and b without constructing an empty matrix and fill its row.

Comment: @QiangHuang `np.multiply.outer(b,a)`